# What adaptation of King Arthur had a femme fatale that turned into a spider?

Tags: story-identification, adaptations, arthurian

I loosely recall seeing an adaption of Arthurian myth that depicted a femme fatale that turned into a spider. IIRC, she tried and failed to seduce and kill one of the knights and was transformed into a normal tarantula as punishment. Or something.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not what you're looking for, but I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Tower_(series), written by Stephen King. At least one of the books seems to include a creature called a "Were-Spider", a human that could take the form of a spider at will. The character I found that was one, however, was not a woman.

Comment: Maybe a title or description from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_works_based_on_Arthurian_legends will ring a bell.

Comment: @Firebat: Nope, none of those have the spider seductress. My memory is fuzzy but I think it was 50s or 60s era movie or show. Maybe color restored.

Comment: I think Morgan Le Fay had such a power in Brian Bolland's "Camelot 3000" for one example, though it's been a while since I read it.